# Best container for search and insert operation for few elements

Tags: c++, c++14

I need to chose a container which will store only a few elements and also no duplicates. I will need later to search after the elements. I thought about set and unordered_set, which will be the best option ?
The set will get its elements one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Just use std::vector.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHNmRkzxHWs&t=2502s) and `std::find(...)` before inserting. If it's already there, don't. If you need it to be sorted, call `std::sort` after successful insert.

Comment: Wouldn't be better a set for std::find() operation ? as far as I know the complexity for a set is O(logN) and for a vector is O(N) ?

Comment: @Cameron121341 You're forgetting that you have a *tiny* dataset. It doesn't matter what you use. As Chandler in the video points out: Sometimes worse is better, i.e. for tiny data sets **bubblesort** will perform better because of the size of the dataset. A linear search for less than millions, (yes, *millions*) of elements is going to perform better.